# Unable to send Activation Email with Djoser in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, email, django-rest-framework

am trying to send activation email when a user get registered . when post request is called the content of email is shown in  console but it is not send to user email.

```
Django setting :
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER=<my_username@gmail.com>
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=<my_password>
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

DJOSER = {
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE' : True,
    'LOGOUT_ON_PASSWORD_CHANGE' : True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_SHOW_EMAIL_NOT_FOUND' : True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL':'#/password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': '#/activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {},
}
```

P.S : SMTP is enabled on gmail account using https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/use-gmail-for-email-in-django/

[Console output after post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDN7o.png)

Comment: The fact that you're seeing the message in the console means that your `EMAIL_BACKEND` setting is wrong - you must be overwriting it somewhere else in your settings file

Comment: @solarissmoke thanks ...i figured out the solution ..problem was in EMAIL_BACKED setting

Comment: @BishnuSharma could you please create an answer to your question, if you managed to resolve this?